# Javascript - array in key/value order to JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, redis

I have the following array (returned by a Redis HSCAN):

```
[ 'foo',
  '1437234647',
  'bar',
  '1437234633' ]
```

This is in the order key, value, key, value etc. I wish to turn this in to a JSON object as follows:

```
{
  "foo": "1437234647",
  "bar": "1437234633"
}
```

How can this be done? Im guessing using odd/even when iterating through the array?

---

Update - heres what I came up with, but looking for a better solution:

```
function keyValueArrayToJson(inArr){

  function isNumber(n) {
    return n == parseFloat(n);
  }

  function isEven(n) {
    return isNumber(n) && (n % 2 == 0);
  }

  var out = {};
  for (var i in inArr) {
    if(isEven(i)){
        out[inArr[i]] = '';
    } else {
        var p = i -1;
        out[inArr[p]] = inArr[i];
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

---

Update 2 - thanks @squint - ordering of the result object is NOT required.

Comment: Have you tried _anything_?

Comment: You seem to be implying that you want the resulting object to be ordered. If so, you can't have that with any guarantee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a `for loop` with `2` as a `step` :

```js
var array = ['foo', '1437234647', 'bar', '1437234633'];
    var object = {};
    for (i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i += 2) {
      object[array[i]] = array[i + 1];
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(object));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes a for loop should do the trick

```js
var arr=[ 'foo','1437234647','bar','1437234633' ];
var obj={};
for(i=0;i<arr.length-1;i+=2){
   obj[arr[i]]=arr[i+1];
}
document.querySelector("pre").textContent = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```